# Generating MathJax latex to html markup with Node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, mathjax, mathml

I'm trying out the `simple/tex2chtml` node example in the [MathJax Node Examples Repository](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax-demos-node).

I'm trying to convert this expression.

```
const latex = `MAD = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n | x_i - \bar{x} |} n`
```

I changed the MathJax invocation to look like this:

```
    MathJax.tex2chtmlPromise(latex, {
        display: !argv.inline,
        em: argv.em,
        ex: argv.ex,
        containerWidth: argv.width
    })
```

The full source looks like this:

```
#! /usr/bin/env -S node -r esm

/*************************************************************************
 *
 *  simple/tex2chtml
 *
 *  Uses MathJax v3 to convert a TeX string to an HTML string.
 *
 * ----------------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 *  Copyright (c) 2019 The MathJax Consortium
 *
 *  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 *  you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 *  You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 *  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 *  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 *  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 *  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 *  limitations under the License.
 */

const latex = `MAD = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n | x_i - \bar{x} |} n`
//
//  The default TeX packages to use
//
const PACKAGES = 'base, autoload, require, ams, newcommand';

//
//  Get the command-line arguments
//
var argv = require('yargs')
    .demand(0).strict()
    .usage('$0 [options] "math" > file.html')
    .options({
        inline: {
            boolean: true,
            describe: "process as inline math"
        },
        em: {
            default: 16,
            describe: 'em-size in pixels'
        },
        ex: {
            default: 8,
            describe: 'ex-size in pixels'
        },
        width: {
            default: 80 * 16,
            describe: 'width of container in pixels'
        },
        packages: {
            default: PACKAGES,
            describe: 'the packages to use, e.g. "base, ams"; use "*" to represent the default packages, e.g, "*, bbox"'
        },
        css: {
            boolean: true,
            describe: 'output the required CSS rather than the HTML itself'
        },
        fontURL: {
            default: 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/output/chtml/fonts/woff-v2',
            describe: 'the URL to use for web fonts'
        },
        assistiveMml: {
            boolean: true,
            default: false,
            describe: 'whether to include assistive MathML output'
        },
        dist: {
            boolean: true,
            default: false,
            describe: 'true to use webpacked version, false to use MathJax source files'
        }
    })
    .argv;

//
// Load MathJax and initialize MathJax and typeset the given math
//
require('mathjax-full').init({
    //
    //  The MathJax configuration
    //
    options: {
        enableAssistiveMml: argv.assistiveMml
    },
    loader: {
        source: (argv.dist ? {} : require('mathjax-full/components/src/source.js').source),
        load: ['adaptors/liteDOM', 'tex-chtml']
    },
    tex: {
        packages: argv.packages.replace('\*', PACKAGES).split(/\s*,\s*/)
    },
    chtml: {
        fontURL: argv.fontURL
    },
    startup: {
        typeset: false
    }
}).then((MathJax) => {
    //
    //  Typeset and display the math
    //
    MathJax.tex2chtmlPromise(latex, {
        display: !argv.inline,
        em: argv.em,
        ex: argv.ex,
        containerWidth: argv.width
    }).then((node) => {
        const adaptor = MathJax.startup.adaptor;
        //
        //  If the --css option was specified, output the CSS,
        //  Otherwise, output the typeset math as HTML
        //
        if (argv.css) {
            console.log(adaptor.textContent(MathJax.chtmlStylesheet()));
        } else {
            console.log(adaptor.outerHTML(node));
        };
    });
}).catch(err => console.log(err));
```

When I run it it produces this error:

```
ole@mkt:~/Temp/MathJax-demos-node$ node simple/tex2chtml
/home/ole/Temp/MathJax-demos-node/node_modules/mathjax-full/components/src/node-main/node-main.js:70
export {init};
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token export
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:720:23)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:643:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:556:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:683:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:16:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ole/Temp/MathJax-demos-node/simple/tex2chtml:83:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:776:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:643:32)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use

```
node -r esm simple/tex2chtml
```

Note the `#! /usr/bin/env -S node -r esm` at the top of the file that indicates `node -r esm` is what is needed to run it.  That is what will enable the ES6 import/export functionality that is being flagged by the error message.